# Blender Video Editor: Clip stays attached to cursor after releasing left click during drag

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I am having a problem with the blender sequence editor and editing clips. Whenever I want to move a clip or trim it, I would hold left click (I set it as left click) to trim/move the clip but when I stop holding left click, the clip or end of the clip still stays attached to my cursor until I click again. Is there a way to set this so that I don't have to click 2 times to trim/move a clip and instead just drag them?[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the clip selected, you can hit 'g' to move (just like the 3D view, the Graph Editor, the Node editor, etc) and use your mouse to reposition the sequence. When you are finished, left-click to accept, or right-click to undo.

I think you will find that this is very easy to use, and, even better (because it is *exactly like the rest of blender*) it is also easy to remember.

Comment: While I do like that while using the 3D viewport and modelling/animating, it completely throws me off for the sequence editor because I'm so used to just dragging the clip and letting go of it to put it in place or to trim it. But if there is no way to enable that feature then I'll just adapt to the 2 mouse clicks to move or using the g button and click.